# Bootstrap dropdown won't appear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get some Bootstrap examples to work, which they all have worked so far except for dropdown, what do I need to add/change on this code to make the dropdown appear?

http://jsbin.com/kuhin/2/edit

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<hr/>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I thought it might also require `dropdown.js` which is not the case when you include the `minified js` file as it includes all the necessary plugins.

However you seem to miss to wrap it in a `<div class="dropdown">`. You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BL78p/1/). Also you are importing `jquery` twice, remove the import at the bottom.

Comment: at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript, it says "bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file. Include only one." so I assumed dropdown.js would be in this file. Where can I get it then?

Comment: adding the `<div class="dropdown">` fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

- You'll want to remove one of the jquery includes as it causes conflict.
- It appears you've removed the parent `div.dropdown` container. As [mentioned](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage) in Bootsrap documentation:

  > Via data attributes or JavaScript, the dropdown plugin toggles hidden content (dropdown menus) by toggling the .open class on the **parent** list item.
- So you need to preserve parent `div.dropdown`:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

- As Tim C mentioned, bootstrap.min.js DOES include dropdown functionality and no further includes are necessary.